# ¿Como puedo volver habilitar el onclick dque tengo en un td?

Tags: javascript

Amigos, una pregunta como puedo volver habilitar el onclick, ya que tengo una funcion que si ya se clickeo una ves, me lo desabilite, pero como es un carrito de compras cuando meten la cantidad y un descuento que pido para que ingrese el usuario se agrega al carrito de compras, pero si por alguna razon eliminan el producto del carrito ahi es donde quiero habilitar denuevo el onclick. pero no se como no me sale, alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo que me explique como, o alguna opcion a la idea que comento, en la funcion de agregarProductoEquipo() ahi esta como anulo el onclick, $("#columnaAdd").prop('onclick', null);.

```js
function abrirContenidoEquipos(){
  var botonEquipos = document.querySelector(".contenidoEquipos");
  botonEquipos.disabled = true;

  var botonEquipos = document.querySelector(".contenidoMsisdn");
  botonEquipos.disabled = false;

  $('#carritoCompraAgregados').hide(); 
  $('#cuerpoCarrito1').show();
  $('#cuerpoCarrito2').show();

  var htmlTbodyEquipos = "";
  var htmlEquiposTotal = 
  "<div class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 form tabla'>"+
    "<table id='totalProductos'>"+
      "<tr class='encabezados'>"+
        "<td class='encabezado'>AGREGAR</td>"+
        "<td class='encabezado'>MARCA</td>"+
        "<td class='encabezado'>MODELO</td>"+
        "<td class='encabezado'>CAPACIDAD</td>"+
        "<td class='encabezado'>PRECIO</td>"+
        "<td class='encabezado'>IMAGEN</td>"+
        // "<td class='encabezado'>STOCK DISPONIBLE</td>"+
      "</tr>"+
      "<tbody class='cuerpoEquipos'>"+
      "</tbody>"+
    "</table>"+
  "</div>";
  
  $(".carritoComprasVista").html(htmlEquiposTotal);

 var jsonData = {
  "platformType": "CerCrm"
  }

  showMessageOverlay("CARGANDO...", "<?=$pointer;?>images/cargando.gif", "200", "200", "sending");

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "<?=$pointer;?>backend/backend_pedidos_mostrar.php",
    data: jsonData,
    success:function(data){
      var resultadoMostrar = JSON.parse(data);
      if(resultadoMostrar["codigo"] == "fallo"){
        if(resultadoMostrar["mensaje"] == ""){
          $(".textoMensaje").text("ERROR.");
        }
        else{
          $(".textoMensaje").text(resultadoMostrar["mensaje"]);
        }

        $("#msj").modal("toggle");

        $(".contenidoUsuarioMonedero").html("");
        closeMessageOverlay();
      }
      else if(resultadoMostrar["codigo"] == "exito"){

        resultadosEquipos = resultadoMostrar["objetoRespuesta"]["equipos"];

        for(var i = 0; i < resultadosEquipos.length; i++) {

          var resultadoTotalEquipos = resultadosEquipos[i];
          // console.log(resultadoTotalEquipos)

          var capacidadEquipo = resultadosEquipos[i]["CAPACIDAD"];
          var idEquipo        = resultadosEquipos[i]["IDEQUIPO"];
          var imagenEquipo    = resultadosEquipos[i]["IMAGEN"];
          var marcaEquipo     = resultadosEquipos[i]["MARCA"];
          var modeloEquipo    = resultadosEquipos[i]["MODELO"];
          var precioEquipo    = resultadosEquipos[i]["PRECIO"];

          var tabla = document.querySelectorAll("#totalProductos tbody tr#filasSelect");
          var ref = tabla.length;
          var num = ref;
          var columna = 1;

          htmlTbodyEquipos += ""+
          "<tr class='resultados trHover' fila='"+num+"' id='filasSelect'>"+
            "<td class='resultado tdClick elementsCenter seleccionImg' id='columnaAdd' columna='"+columna+"' onClick='clickAbrirPopupPedidoCarrito("+idEquipo+", 0, "+columna+", "+num+");'>"+
              "<div class='imgAgregar'></div>"+
            "</td>"+
            "<td class='resultado'>"+marcaEquipo+"</td>"+
            "<td class='resultado'>"+modeloEquipo+"</td>"+
            "<td class='resultado'>"+capacidadEquipo+"</td>"+
            "<td class='resultado'>$"+precioEquipo+"</td>"+
            "<td class='resultado'>"+
              "<div><img src='../images/dispositivos/"+imagenEquipo+" 'alt='movil' style='width: 30px; height: 30px;'></div>"+
            "</td>"+
          "</tr>";

          $("#buscarArticulos").removeClass("hide");
          $(".cuerpoEquipos").html(htmlTbodyEquipos);
          // console.log(num);
          closeMessageOverlay();
        }
      }  
    }
  });      
}
```

```js
function clickIngresarCarritoEquipo(){

    for(var i = 0; i < resultadosEquipos.length; i++) {
      var resultadoTotalEquipos = resultadosEquipos[i];

      var capacidadEquipo = resultadosEquipos[i]["CAPACIDAD"];
      var idEquipo        = resultadosEquipos[i]["IDEQUIPO"];
      var imagenEquipo    = resultadosEquipos[i]["IMAGEN"];
      var marcaEquipo     = resultadosEquipos[i]["MARCA"];
      var modeloEquipo    = resultadosEquipos[i]["MODELO"];
      var precioEquipo    = resultadosEquipos[i]["PRECIO"];

      if (idEquipoSeleccionado == idEquipo) {
        
        var htmlEquiposAgregados =
        "<span class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetasTextoMediano'>Ingresa la cantidad para tu pedido</span>"+
        "<br>"+
        "<img class='colLg12 colLgPush10 colMd12 colMdPush10 colSm24 colSmPush00 colXs24 colXsPush00 imagenProducto' src='../images/dispositivos/"+imagenEquipo+" 'alt='movil' style='width: 120px;'>"+
        "<p class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetasTextoMediano infoProducto'>"+marcaEquipo+" "+modeloEquipo+" "+capacidadEquipo+"</p>"+
        "<p class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetasTextoMediano'>$ "+precioEquipo+"</p>"+
        "<div class='colLg12 colMd12 colSm24 colXs24'>"+
          "<p class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetaFija centerText'>CANTIDAD *</p>"+
          "<input class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24' type='number' name='cantidadEquiposIngreso' id='cantidadEquiposIngreso' min='0' onKeypress='return soloNumerosDecimales(event);' placeholder='CANTIDAD'/>"+
        "</div>"+
        "<div class='colLg12 colMd12 colSm24 colXs24'>"+
          "<p class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetaFija centerText'>DESCUENTO *</p>"+
          "<input class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24' type='text' name='descuentoEquiposIngreso' id='descuentoEquiposIngreso' placeholder='DESCUENTO' maxlength='2' onKeypress='return soloNumeros(event);'/>"+
        "</div>";

        var htmlBotones =
        "<div type='button' class='popupBtnCerrar closePopupAgregarPedido' data-dismiss='modal'><div class='cancelar'></div>Cancelar</div>"+
        "<div type='button' class='popupBtnConfirmar' onClick='agregarProductoEquipo("+idEquipo+", "+precioEquipo+");'><div class='continuar'></div>Continuar</div>";
        
        $(".contenidoAgregarPedido").html(htmlEquiposAgregados);
        $(".divBotonesPedidos").html(htmlBotones);
      }
    }
  }
```

```js
function agregarProductoEquipo(idEquipo, precioEquipo){
  var catidadIngresada = $("#cantidadEquiposIngreso").val();
  var descuentoIngresado = $("#descuentoEquiposIngreso").val();

  if ((fila >= 0) && (columnas == 1)){
    if ((descuentoIngresado) && (catidadIngresada)) {
      var filas = document.querySelectorAll("#filasSelect");
      filas[fila].style.backgroundColor = "#A9F7BB";
      $("#columnaAdd").prop('onclick', null);
    }
  }

  var infoProducto = $(".infoProducto").text();
  var imagenProducto = $(".imagenProducto").attr('src');


  var descuento = (precioEquipo*descuentoIngresado)/100;

  var totalDescuento = precioEquipo - descuento;

  var total = 0;
  var htmlEquiposAgregados = "";

  total = catidadIngresada;
  var totalCantidadPrecio = total * totalDescuento;


  htmlEquiposAgregados +=

    "<tr class='resultados trHover'>"+
      "<td class='resultado'><img src='"+imagenProducto+"' alt='movil' style='width: 80px;'></td>"+
      "<td class='resultado'>"+infoProducto+"<input type='hidden' class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 idProductoTabla' value='"+idEquipo+"'/></td>"+
      "<td class='resultado'><input class='colLg12 colLgPush06 colMd12 colMdPush06 colSm24 colSmPush00 colXs24 colXsPush00 totalCantidad' type='number' name='cantidadTotalEquipos' min='0' onKeypress='return soloNumerosDecimales(event);' value='"+catidadIngresada+"'/></td>"+
      "<td class='resultado'>%"+descuentoIngresado+"<input type='hidden' class='colLg12 colLgPush06 colMd12 colMdPush06 colSm24 colSmPush00 colXs24 colXsPush00 descuentoEquipoSeleccionado' value='"+descuentoIngresado+"'/></td>"+
      "<td class='resultado'>$"+precioEquipo+"<input type='hidden' class='colLg12 colLgPush06 colMd12 colMdPush06 colSm24 colSmPush00 colXs24 colXsPush00 precioEquipoSeleccionado' value='"+precioEquipo+"'/></td>"+
      "<td class='resultado tdClick elementsCenter seleccionImg' onClick='eliminarElemento(this, "+idEquipo+", "+totalCantidadPrecio+");'>"+
        "<input type='hidden' class='totalEquipos' value='"+totalCantidadPrecio+"'>"+
        "<div class='imgEliminar'></div>"+
      "</td>"+
    "</tr>";

    $('.contenidoEquiposTotalCarrito').append(htmlEquiposAgregados);

  $(".closePopupAgregarPedido").click();

  var suma = 0;
  $('.totalEquipos').each(function(){

    if (!isNaN($(this).val())) {
      suma += Number($(this).val());
      $(".totalEquiposText").text(moneda+suma.toLocaleString('es-MX'));
      $(".campoTotalEquipos").val(suma);
    }else{console.log("NAN");}
  });

  obtenerValoresTabla();
}

function obtenerValoresTabla() {
  var trs=document.querySelectorAll("#equiposAnadidosCarrito .resultados");
    for (var tr of trs) {
      var inputs=tr.querySelectorAll("input");
      var arrIdEquipo = inputs[0].value;
      var arrCatidad = inputs[1].value;
      var arrDescuento = inputs[2].value;
      var arrPrecio = inputs[3].value;
      var arrTotal = inputs[4].value;

      produAgre = {
            idEquipo: arrIdEquipo,
            cantidad: arrCatidad,
            descuento: arrDescuento,
            precioUnitario: arrPrecio,
            totalDescuento: arrTotal
        };
    }
    prodArray.push(produAgre);
}
```

```js
function eliminarElemento(valor, idEquipo, totalCantidadPrecio){

  var totalEliminar = $(".campoTotalEquipos").val();
  var elimProd = totalEliminar - totalCantidadPrecio;

  $(".totalEquiposText").text(moneda+elimProd.toFixed(2));
  valor.closest('tr').remove();

  if ((fila >= 0) && (columnas == 1)){
    var filas = document.querySelectorAll("#filasSelect");
    filas[fila].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando deshabilitas:
(guardamos el valor antiguo en data-onclick)

```
$("#columnaAdd").attr('data-onclick',  $("#columnaAdd").attr('onclick'));
$("#columnaAdd").attr('onclick', null);
```

Cuando Habilitas:

```
$("#columnaAdd").attr('onclick',  $("#columnaAdd").attr('data-onclick'));
```